# trouble hosting asp.net on iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, timeout

I'm doing some test hosting of an asp.net program I created

I can access it fine from the local machine (both debugging and pointing the virtual directory to it)

I can also access (local) by using the localhost or using the ip

however when i get on a different machine on the same network (i can ping my machine)

I get the following error:

```
Connection Interrupted

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.


The network link was interrupted while negotiating a connection. Please try again.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Crash893

EDIT:

[I have duplicate this question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/58773/trouble-hosting-asp-net-on-xp-iis)

Comment: I think that, since this seems to be a server issue, that it would belong more on http://serverfault.com . I have voted to close this question, and if five more people do so, it will be migrated there automagically! Whoopee!

Comment: 1) Do you have windows firewall turned on, on the server? 2) Is the script trying some ajaxy stuff?

Comment: Are there any messages in the Windows Application Event log related to this problem?

Comment: I was unsure if it was a SF or SO thing sorry.

Comment: @tangurena  I haven't changed anything from defuatls what sort of firewall change should i make?

Comment: @jeff S there doesnt appear to be anything in the system or security logs is there anything else i can check?

Answer (score 0):

I would generally take a snapshot of the network traffic with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (or other network sniffer) and see what is happening on the wire. Compare this to a site that works. Windows firewall, a browser proxy, or some other network software may be at fault.